# Магнит и магнетизм

Tags: словообразование

МагнИт и магнЕтизм.  Как объяснить чередование гласных и//е?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово *магн**и**т* заимствовано из церковнославянского *магн**и**тъ*, восходящего к греческому *magn**i**tis* 'магнетский камень'.

Слово *магн**е**тизм* заимствовано из французского *magn**é**tisme*, восходящего к тому же греческому корню.

Так, у слов просто разные источники заимствования, в которых, соответственно, происходили разные фонетические изменения. Чередование в современном русском не обусловлено какими-либо внутриязыковыми законами.

Источники: "Этимологический словарь современного русского языка" А. К. Шапошникова и "Толковый словарь русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов" РАН.

Comment: Спасибо! Мы говорим (и пишем) "магнит", но магнетизм", хотя оба слова происходят от греческого "Магнезия" - имени той области Древней Греции, где впервые был обнаружен магнитный железняк. Как возникла такая двойственность? В разные периоды истории греческого языка буква "η" его азбуки ("эта, "ита")
произносилась различно: то как "е", то как "и". Поэтому если слова одного корня заимствовались другими языками в разное время, они могли прибыть туда в неодинаковом звучании. Имел значение и путь, которым они передавались из языка в язык. Лев Успенский. "Почему не иначе?"

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова да-да, хорошее объяснение из замечательной старой книжки :)